Java Socket not binding to an Apple Silicon computer
I have been experimenting with communication with Java's Socket and DataStream libraries. I am using 2 files: Client and Server. I start the Server on one terminal window and then connect to it using the Client on a separate terminal. The client sends messages to the server and the server prints them out. They both exit when the Client types "Over". It worked perfectly fine when I used localhost on my computer, but when I sent my Client file to my friend, on a Windows machine, and had him try to connect to my laptop, an Apple silicon MacBook, it gave the exception

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

From what I can tell this means the socket can't bind to the IP address/port on my computer. I thought it would be a problem with my IP address, port, or firewall. Considering macOS's Privacy and Security settings, I think it might be the firewall. Two files are listed below. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I did not use localhost (127.0.0.1) in the Client file, I used my IP address.
Client.java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {
    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream input;
    private DataOutputStream output;
    private String username;
    private String message;
    private static String address;
    private static int port;

    public Client(String address, int port) {

        // begin the socket, input stream, and output stream
        try {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("UPDATE: Socket started");

            input = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            System.out.println("UPDATE: Input Stream Started.");

            output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("UPDATE: Output Stream Started.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: An IO exception occured while attempting to start the socket and input/output streams.");
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: An unknown exception occured while attemption to start the socket and input/output streams.");
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // get the user's username
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter a username: ");
            username = input.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: An IO exception occured while attempting to get your username.");
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        message = "";

        // send the message to the server
        while (!message.equals("Over")) { // over is the stop word
            try {
                System.out.print(">");
                message = input.readLine();
                output.writeUTF(username + ": " + message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: An IO exception occured while attemption to send a message");
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        // close the socket, input stream, and output stream
        try {
            input.close();
            output.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("An IO exception occured while attemption go close the socket and input/output streams.");
               System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        address = "127.0.0.1";
        port = 9000;
        Client client = new Client(address, port);
    }
}

Server.java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    private Socket socket;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private DataInputStream input;
    private static int port;

    public Server(int port) {

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server socket started.");

            System.out.println("Waiting for client connection...");

            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connection achieved");

            input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";

            while (!line.equals("Over")) {
                try {
                    line = input.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(line);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("An IO exception occured while recieving a message.");
                    System.out.println(e);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Closing connection");

            socket.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An IO exception occured.");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        port = 9000;
        Server server = new Server(port);
    }
}

Me and my friend tried changing the port, but It didn't work. I don't know what else I can do.

What happens if you do use localhost IP address?

Can your friend - who is running your client - ping your computer that is running the server? In order for the computer, running the client, to establish a socket connection to the computer running the server, both computers need to be on the same network. As far as I am aware, if ping doesn't succeed, then a socket connection cannot be established.

Share also the messages from the applications. And try failing on error instead of continuing.

Try binding to INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0).

This is not a programming question. It is about networking, and how to configure the various computers / routers / firewalls etc to allow the connections to happen.  The connection timeouts are a symptom of a networking problem, not a programming problem.  Ask this on ServerFault or AskDifferent.
